# How to pass input to main sub in Visual Studio console application for an exe to be run in batch mode?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, console

I am new in Visual studio. I am supposed to create an exe file to be run in batch mode. The exe will read a text file and output another text file. The names of the two text files are the inputs off the application. After creating the exe file, I will run it in the batch mode.

The batch file will be something like (run_exe.bat)
app.exe input_file.txt output_file.txt

My code is below. The problem is to put inputs (file names) to main sub. I receive a strange error at the line a3 = a1 + a2 as "an unhandled exception of type System.IO.IOexception occurred in microsoft.visualbasic.dll"

I think the problem is the inputs fil_na1 and fil_na2. Where should I put those inputs?

My code is as follows:

Module Module1

```
Sub Main(ByVal fil_na1 As String, ByVal fil_na2 As String)

    Dim fil_nu1 As Integer
    fil_nu1 = FreeFile()

    FileOpen(fil_nu1, fil_na1, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared)

    Dim str_lin As String
    Dim a1 As Integer, a2 As Integer

    str_lin = FileSystem.LineInput(fil_nu1)
    a1 = Val(str_lin)

    str_lin = FileSystem.LineInput(fil_nu1)
    a2 = Val(str_lin)

    FileSystem.FileClose(fil_nu1)

    Dim a3 As Integer
    a3 = a1 + a2

    Dim fil_nu2 As Integer
    fil_nu2 = FreeFile()

    FileOpen(fil_nu2, fil_na2, OpenMode.Output, OpenAccess.Write, OpenShare.Shared)
    FileSystem.WriteLine(fil_nu2, a3)
    FileSystem.FileClose(fil_nu2)

End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the command lines with this function.

[Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can see them like this

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length)

For Each commandArgument As String In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    Console.WriteLine(commandArgument)
Next
```

Now it's all about parsing the array, making sure you have enough argument and that they are valid.

Also, instead of using FileOpen I would suggest you use the functionality of the System.IO namespace.

Comment: thanks for your response. But, I can not use any command line or else. my application will not have any interaction with the user. In other words, I have two separate applications (2 exes) one of them calling the other one. Like the engineering programs. One has the user interface and the other one is the solver. The solver has no interaction with the user and run from the main application directly with a number of input text files.

Comment: Ugh. It worked. thx a lot and sorry. I even did not know that i was trying to get command line data:) so... more respect to the experts:)))